# jquery encode string for mailto link

Tags: jquery

I have this variable like so:

```
var htmlBody = "<table border = '1' cellspacing='0' align = 'center'><tr><th>Job #</th><th>Task</th><th>Date</th></tr></table>”;
```

which I will be using for to generate a mailto link:

```
window.location = "mailto:?subject=Schedule&body=" + htmlBody;
```

My question is, is it possible encode the html in my string for this purpose? So I do not have the html markup in the email body.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use encodeURI
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

Example:

```
var encoded=encodeURIComponent("<span>Hello, im <b>html</b></span>.");
```

The result is

```
"%3Cspan%3EHello%2C%20im%20%3Cb%3Ehtml%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E."
```

Then use it to build your querystring.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `encodeURIComponent` & `replace` for encoding the `htmlBody`.
`encodeURIComponent` function encodes the following characters: `, / ? : @ & = + $ #`. to encode `'`, using replace

```js
var htmlBody = "<table border = '1' cellspacing='0' align = 'center'><tr><th>Job #</th><th>Task</th><th>Date</th></tr></table>";
var encodedURL = encodeURIComponent("mailto:?subject=Schedule&body=" + htmlBody).replace(/'/g, "%27");
console.log(encodedURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can only set the `body` of the email to plain text.

`mailto` type URLs are a well-defined URI schema. They're defined in [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368). In section 2 it says that the `body` field must be `text/plain`

(Although, it may be worth noting that some mail clients might extend the mailto URL schema? i.e., perhaps Outlook or Gmail would support it while others wouldn't.)